# Расстановка скобок

Tags: пунктуация

В каких случаях слова в тексте берутся в скобки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В скобки берутся слова или предложения, являющиеся пояснением к основному тексту. Они могут быть как связаны с основным текстом, так и не связаны.
Примеры: *Через две мили (примерно 4 км.) поле сменилось лесом. Она опоздала (кто бы мог подумать!) всего на полчаса*.
Кроме того, в случае цитирования, в скобки берется фамилия автора.
Пример: *"Государство - это я" (Людовик XIV).*

Answer (score 0):

Вводные предложения, когда в них содержатся дополнительные сведения: Петровский (ему тогда было двадцать лет) был необычайно хорош собой.